# Using SSL Certificates with shared hosting/different domain provider

Tags: domains, security, https, security-certificate

I need to add a HTTPS address to an existing domain. Unfortunately there two companies involved: One for shared web-hosting, and one for the domain.

How do SSL Certificated domains work in such instances? Does the company who hosts the domain issue the SSL Certificate? Or is it the web-hosting company that the domain points to?

Additionally, are they usually considered separate to their normal HTTP counterparts, with me needing to update their name servers manually (and transfer to the new hosting)? Or are they part of the same domain, and so I won't need to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy your SSL certificate from any provider and then it is installed into your web hosting.

When you purchase the SSL certificate, you specify the specific domain it is for.

It is usually convenient to buy the SSL certificate from your web hosting provider as they may install it for you as part of the service, or at least be in a good position to help if you have any difficulty.

Comment: How can you buy a domain certificate through a company that doesn't have access to the domain itself...? :-/

Comment: As per edit, you specify the domain it is for when you buy it.

Answer (score 1):

The web hosting company will issue a CSR for you and you have to submit this CSR at your SSL certificate provider.

Once SSL is issued, you will have to provide SSL Certificate (provided by SSL provider) & the CA Bundle to your hosting provider. They will install it on your domain name.

Note: For the SSL certificate, you will need to order a dedicated IP as the addon at your web hosting provider.